Trigger returns Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is
I have this trigger, and it throws this error:

Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression

I know the inserted and deleted may return multiple rows, but I can't find a way to solve this.
USE [BIOAGRO]
GO

/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[SaldoDet]    Script Date: 9/11/2024 7:37:18 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[SaldoDet]
ON [dbo].[CxC_Transacciones_Det]
AFTER INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Action AS char(1);

        SET @Action = (CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED)
                                 AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED)
                                THEN 'U'  -- Set Action to Updated.
                            WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED)
                                THEN 'I'  -- Set Action to Insert.
                            WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED)
                                THEN 'D'  -- Set Action to Deleted.
                       END)
        IF @Action = 'I' OR @Action = 'U'
            UPDATE cxc_transacciones_enc 
            SET saldo = dbo.saldofactura(i.cod_cliente, i.compania, 'RD', i.doc_tipo_aplica, i.doc_numero_aplica) 
            FROM cxc_transacciones_enc e 
            INNER JOIN inserted i ON e.Compania = i.Compania 
                                  AND e.Cod_Cliente = i.Cod_Cliente 
                                  AND e.Doc_Tipo = i.Doc_Tipo_Aplica 
                                  AND e.Doc_Numero = i.Doc_Numero_Aplica

        IF @Action = 'D'
            UPDATE cxc_transacciones_enc 
            SET saldo = dbo.saldofactura(d.cod_cliente, d.compania, 'RD', d.doc_tipo_aplica, d.doc_numero_aplica) 
            FROM cxc_transacciones_enc e 
            INNER JOIN deleted d ON e.Compania = d.Compania 
                                 AND e.Cod_Cliente = d.Cod_Cliente 
                                 AND e.Doc_Tipo = d.Doc_Tipo_Aplica 
                                 AND e.Doc_Numero = d.Doc_Numero_Aplica
    END

I update all the cxc_transacciones_det rows to update the column saldo in table cxc_transacciones_enc, and get the error.
I need to update the column saldo in table cxc_transacciones_enc when something happens in its detail table, cxc_transacciones_det
This is the function
USE [XXXXXX]
GO

/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[Saldofactura]    Script Date: 9/11/2024 10:21:01 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Saldofactura]
    (@Cliente nvarchar(12), 
     @Cia char(6), 
     @Moneda char(2), 
     @Tipo tinyint, 
     @Factura nvarchar(10))
RETURNS Money
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Debito Money, @Credito Money, @Saldo money

    IF UPPER(@moneda) = 'RD'
    BEGIN
        SET @Saldo = (SELECT SUM(valor * (CASE WHEN doc_tipo IN (1,2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) - 
                             SUM((valor + ISNULL(descuento, 0)) * (CASE WHEN doc_tipo IN (3,4,5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))
                      FROM CxC_Transacciones_Det
                      WHERE Compania = @cia 
                        AND cod_cliente = @cliente  
                        AND doc_tipo_aplica = @Tipo 
                        AND doc_numero_aplica = @Factura)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @Saldo = (SELECT SUM(valor * (CASE WHEN doc_tipo IN (1,2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) 
                             - SUM((valor + ISNULL(descuento, 0)) * (CASE WHEN doc_tipo IN (3,4,5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))
                      FROM CxCUS_Transacciones_Det
                      WHERE Compania = @cia 
                        AND cod_cliente = @cliente  
                        AND doc_tipo_aplica = @Tipo 
                        AND doc_numero_aplica = @Factura)
    END

    RETURN ISNULL(ROUND(@Saldo, 2), 0)
END


Your code looks fine, i'm guessing the issue is in saldofactura function

I ran a code in a program doping the same thing, for every record in the detail table. Saldofactura function didn't return the error.

OK. Please append the function code and also the whole error message with line number and procedure etc. Could be there are more triggers, who knows

It doesn't matter whether the subqueries return more than record or not, since they are used in a EXISTS(subquery) which always returns one value.

The function looks good to me. Strange. Are you running sql server 2022 by chance? Also, what's the whole error message?

Is there a trigger on cxc_transacciones_enc as well?

I will admit, I doubt that function is performant. If you can switch it to an inline table value function, you'll likely see a decent performance boon (especially as that will improve the speed of your trigger, which are meant to be designed to have as minimal impact as possible).

WOW! you were right, there is another trigger in the cxc_transacciones_enc table that Im trying to update. Thank you very much

And let me guess, that trigger suffers from The Silent Bug or "abuse" found in many triggers?

Thom, I don't know how can I do that with that function, I wish

Seems like this would work.

I see it returns a table, what I need to do is update the column 'saldo' (balance} for those invoices in cxc_transacciones_enc. Why I do that? because if use the function in some querys, it takes a lot of time to process, so the only solution I find is to add that trigger

"because if use the function in some querys [sic], it takes a lot of time to process" Yes, I had already mentioned that I expected that function to be awful for performance: "I will admit, I doubt that function is performant." and why I suggested switching to an iTVF.  Moving a slow function to be used in a TRIGGER  is actually a terrible idea, as now your DML statements are slow.

I see, but I don't know how to solve this.

How do experts manage invoices balances on huge tables? That would be useful to know.
